# Google's NavigationDrawer not drawing correctly over map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, navigation-drawer

I'm having this issue with Google's NavigationDrawer not drawing correctly over the map when I pull it out from the side of the screen, it's being drawn under the map instead of over it, when closing it from already being open it is shown correctly.

The [first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p11FJ.jpg) is closing it, the [second pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trYDy.jpg) is opening it. This is occurring on a Galaxy S3 running 4.1 but on my Galaxy nexus 4.2 there's no issue. I had a similar issue with a `ViewPager` and `Map` a while ago that could be fixed by putting the map inside a `FrameLayout` with another framelayout over it, but that was on pre-ICS devices. If I had to guess this has to do with hardware acceleration.

[Here's a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7i5oeCvI3Y) of the bug in action on YouTube.

Answer (score 31):

Just using [DrawerLayout.bringChildToFront(View)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#bringChildToFront(android.view.View)) didn't work for me, although I added a [DrawerLayout.requestLayout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#requestLayout()) call and it did it!

Here's the code

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(...) {

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
        super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        drawerLayout.bringChildToFront(drawerView);
        drawerLayout.requestLayout();
    }

    ...
}

drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Note that the `bringChildToFront()` documentation has been updated to say that `invalidate()` should _also_ be called: "Prior to `KITKAT` this method should be followed by calls to `requestLayout()` and `invalidate()` on this parent to force the parent to redraw with the new child ordering."

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem on few devices. I decided to add transparent view on top of MapFragment(that is whole content frame). That seems to work, both drawer and shadow are drawn properly without performance issues. I didn't have to add any additional code in `onDrawerSlide` or `onDrawerStateChanged` methods. As a background for that additional view I used transparent 9patch.

Layout xml file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/search_result_height"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <!-- Transparent View -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/transparent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/foreground"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider_drawer_list"
        android:dividerHeight="1px"
        tools:ignore="PxUsage" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Instead of using a transparent drawable just use @android:color/transparent. This is a lighter footprint and works the same.

Comment: @Lecho Can you tell if the problem is still present on Android 3.x? I am unsure whether I put the normal layout into `layout-v11` for Android 3.x or `layout-v14` for Android 4.x.

Comment: I had this problem on few devices with android 4.x, I don't know how about android 3.x but problem is definitely present on some devices with android 4.x. I'm not sure if this problem is related to android version, gpu driver or something else.

Answer (score 6):

i fixed this issue in this way:
when you create your ActionBarDrawerToggle, after 'opened' and 'closed' events, you have to manage also the 'slide' event, in order to bring the drawer to front, like that

```
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
{
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    mDrawerLayout.bringChildToFront(drawerView);
}
```

Comment: Sadly I can't check if this works anymore easily. Moved the project over to SlidingMenu after no one answered for a few days. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to work around this issue by bringing the drawer to front in each `onDrawerStateChanged()` **and** `onDrawerSlide()`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private View mDrawerView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
        mDrawerLayout = ( DrawerLayout ) findViewById( R.id.drawer_layout );
        mDrawerView = findViewById( R.id.left_drawer );
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle( this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.topbar_menu, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close )
        {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide ( View drawerView, float slideOffset )
        {
            bringDrawerToFront();
            super.onDrawerSlide( drawerView, slideOffset );
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged ( int newState )
        {
            bringDrawerToFront();
            super.onDrawerStateChanged( newState );
        }
        private void bringDrawerToFront()
        {
            mDrawerView.bringToFront();
            mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();
        }           
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener( mDrawerToggle );
    }

}
```

A little drawback is that the dimmed background is still under the map.